# wait() and Thread.sleep() Dont work

Tags: java

Im trying to make picture move across a canvas.

```
import java.awt.*; class GraphicsProgram extends Canvas{

static int up = 0;



    public GraphicsProgram(){
        setSize(700, 700);
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argS){

         //GraphicsProgram class is now a type of canvas
          //since it extends the Canvas class
          //lets instantiate it
         GraphicsProgram GP = new GraphicsProgram();   
        //create a new frame to which we will add a canvas
        Frame aFrame = new Frame();
        aFrame.setSize(700, 700);

        //add the canvas
        aFrame.add(GP);

        aFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){


        Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Code.jpg"); 
        g.drawImage(img1, up, up, this);         }

public void  Move() {   up = up + 1;    Move();


    Thread.sleep(2000);
      }


}
```

The console then returns

> GraphicsProgram.java:43: error: unreported exception
>   InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
>       Thread.sleep(2000);
>                   ^ 1 error

I really can not understand why my `Thread.sleep()` is not working as I have searched it up and this is exactly what they put.

Comment: `"I really can not understand why my Thread.sleep() is not working as I have searched it up and this is exactly what they put."` -- Please show a link to a highly up-voted answer here that puts a Thread.sleep in the middle of a painting method. The solution you need is a Swing Timer, not `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's bad practice to use `Thread.sleep()` inside the `Move` method.  But, if that's what you intend to do:

This is a compilation error complaining that there's an exception that might not get caught, try surrounding your `Thread.sleep(2000)` with a try-catch statement, example:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Again, every one is fixing the compilation problem but giving the wrong suggestions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You are correct, I edited the post to make sure OP understands :)

Answer (score 0):

`InterruptedException` is a checked Exception and you have to `catch` it as shown below:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But, as @Hovercraft highlighted, calling sleep in the painting method is not a good practice.

Comment: You're answering the XY Problem, not the real problem. Calling sleep in the painting method is bad, whether you pretty it up and make it compile or not.